# can't add meteor package

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm taking an Eduonix tutorial about meteor and I'm using joshowens, but it sends me this error while I'm trying to add the package:
"joshowens:accounts-entry INCOMPATIBLE WITH METEOR 0.9 OR LATER".

And as long as I'm working on windows it doesn't allow me to downgrade my Meteor version, could you help me?

Comment: what's the help that you are looking for? how to downgrade meteor to a version < 0.9 on windows? It seems a little drastic to lock yourself into an old version of the platform just because one package isn't available for the latest version. Isn't there any other alternative package you could use?

Comment: @Jaime That package is old and busted. You should pick a more recent tutorial.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? It's a good question, and the answer below probably just saved me hours of research. You can follow the bug report here: https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry/issues/383

Answer (score 7):

For Meteor 1.2.0.1 version the following should work:

meteor add check

meteor add selaias:accounts-entry

Comment: Thank you  for sharing, it helped.

Comment: That was really helpful. Thanks